# Why didn't Jinbe and Ace wear prisoner uniforms?

Tags: one-piece

Ivankof and the others also didn't wear a uniform, but they're part of some kind of underworld society, so they're basically running away; but Jinbe and Ace are prisoners, so why they didn't wear uniforms?

**Jinbe**

[image]

**Ace**

[image]

Comment: interesting question. if i have to guess it would be something along the lines of that they were not expected to stay long in there so a uniform wasn't needed

Comment: I don't believe there is a definite answer (which is why this is a comment) for either but especially Jinbe. It is worth noting, however, that Gol. D Rodger was not in uniform when executed. A likely minor curtosy afforded those waiting execution could be the right to wear their own clothes for their final hours. This would make them more recognizable in this odd world where people wear one outfit for months. Jinbe was clearly a special case and would likely have been released after execution and he had been shown his place. This is all speculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jimbei was officially a Shichibukai until he verbally told to Sengoku at Marineford that he is resigning. He was imprisoned just because he didn't follow World Government orders. So there is no reason why he should be wearing prison uniform as he was not a convict.

As for Ace, I think [kaine](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8126/why-didnt-jinbe-and-ace-wear-prisoner-uniforms/8133#comment9929_8126) must be right. It must be like when Gol. D Rodger was not in uniform when executed. A likely minor courtesy afforded those waiting execution could be the right to wear their own clothes for their final hours.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is may be they were new in the prison and were supposed to be there for a short amount of time.

Ace : he was going to be executed. So there was no reason to give him a proper uniform.
Jimbei : he was opposing the war but his decision was not final until he said so to sengoku at marin ford. I mean to say is there was a chance that he would support the government.

This is just my speculation don't know if it makes sense